# What is the difference between $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" (note double quotes)?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some commands in http://example.com/test/sub/index.php file to echo out the php derivative values. 
For the following address in the address bar I get:
http://example.com/test/sub/index.php/blahblah

```
$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]: /test/sub/index.php

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']: example.com

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']: /test/sub/index.php/blahblah

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URl']:

"$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']": /test/sub/index.php/blahblah
```

Why 'REQUEST_URl' returns null if used without quotation marks?

I am trying to debug my RewriteRule in .htaccess and I need 'REQUEST_URl' to return the path as "/test/sub/index.php/blahblah" or even it will be better if I can get "index.php/blahblah"

Comment: superglobals are always in uppercase! e.g. `$_SERVER`

Comment: It looks like you're using REQUEST_URL (with a lowercase 'L').

Comment: Thanks. the word SERVER was in uppercase, I corrected my question to reflect this. But this called my attention to the the fact that in my code I was using REQUEST_URl (lowercase L) instead of REQUEST_URI (uppercase i). I had copy-pasted this code from internet. I corrected the typo and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use superglobals, do it in UPPERCASE. For example if you really want to return FULL adress, you could do it like this:

```
$real_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```